# Is there a relational database that serves records in JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, rdbms

I know there are tons of NOSQL databases that chose JSON as the native format in which the data is stored. I wonder if there is a **relational database** (operates on plain tuples rather than hierarchical documents) that serves records as JSON objects and as convenient to use from under NodeJS as, say MongoDB is.

Answer (score 2):

As a relational database, Postgres has the capability to store JSON columns, see [here](http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/) for example. It's performance is also rather sleek.

Comment: Official docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ORMs which support mapping relational databases to JSON objects which can be manipulated in Node:

- http://sequelizejs.com/
- https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2
- https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline